# What was Ramirez's nationality?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

Juan Ramirez claimed to be both Spanish and Egyptian, had spent some time in feudal era Japan (I don't know if he ever directly refers to it as Japan, but if he did then he officially has the power to see the future) and he is a white man with a Scottish accent.  This is quite confusing and clearly Ramirez is lying.

My question is this:  **is his actual place of origin ever officially or explicitly stated?**

Comment: Moreso than a guy with a clearly French accent is supposed to be Scottish?

Comment: And then he was replaced by that Anglo-Italian guy who was also supposed to be Scottish.

Comment: Right.  I don't have the quotes, but casting choices aside Ramirez says he's Egyptian and has traveled to Spain and Japan, and is probably old enough that his accent has gotten muddled.

Comment: But I don't know why he's white.

Comment: That'd be because they cast a white actor. Might as well ask why Moses and Cleopatra were white in The Ten Commandments and Cleopatra, respectively.

Comment: True.  Although I just thought of an interesting possible in-universe answer.  All immortals are foundlings.  So their race does not have to correspond to their place of origin.

Comment: Tome it seems like all the peoples who live around the Mediterranean Sea like Moses and Cleopatra are white, even if they aren't as white as I am.  Do you have some very restricted definition of white.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as we're aware, Ramirez was born in Egypt in approximately 896 B.C. His given name was Tak Ne and he first quickened after being run over by a cart in his home town.

> **MACLEOD:** *I can't swim -- you Spanish pea-cock.*
>
> Their angry voices carry across the lake.
>
> **RAMIREZ:** *I am not Spanish. I am Egyptian.*
>
> <sub><sup>[*Highlander* - Final Draft Screenplay](https://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt)</sup></sub>

and

> **RAMIREZ:** *When I was young, a cart ran over me. I should have died. But the wound healed by itself.*
>
> <sub><sup>[*Highlander* - Final Draft Screenplay](https://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt)</sup></sub>

Much of this is confirmed in the [*Way of the Sword*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(comics)#Highlander:_Way_of_the_Sword) comic book serial which acts as a sequel to the *Highlander* movie.

[image: comic panel depicting a man in an orange suit sitting, reading "My name is Tak Ne, and I am unlike most humans in this world; I am an Immortal"]

---

In the second film of the series, we learn that he was in fact born on the Planet [Zeist](https://highlander.wikia.com/wiki/Zeist), some 5000 years before the events of the first Highlander film. This would explain his lighter skin and atypically Egyptian looks.

Comment: great answer, but if I may suggest an edit.  Ramirez was not born in Egypt.  No immortals are born, they are all foundlings.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster - That fact was a retcon added by the TV series.

Comment: Really?  Thanks for the info.  I love Highlander as a concept, but I have a feeling that the continuity and lore was made up as they went along.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster - The continuity in the later films is bafflingly complex. In the original it was pretty simple stuff. Some people are born immortal. They're drawn to fight with each other when they encounter each other. The winner gets their "spark" and when there are a small enough number, they'll be irresistibly drawn together to fight.

Comment: There were *two* "Highlander 2" movies.  Continuity and canon are not really strong suits for this franchise.

Comment: @Steve-O - There was only one Highlander 2 movie, I'm afraid.

Comment: You're all wrong. There was only one movie, *Highlander*. Sadly, there were no sequels nor TV shows.

Comment: @AndresF. --- Lots of people seem to think that Robocop also has sequels and a TV series. Some even imagined that there was a remake. Strange.

Comment: @AndresF. Maybe we should make one! In fact I do have some ideas for the sequels (high technology shields protecting cities from the Sun, the immortals are actually aliens, some evil guy who can project illusions) I am thinking about starting a crowdfunding. Are you interested in?